# It's 2020 September. How big is the Ethereum blockchain when download a full node?

Tags: blockchain, full-node, blockchain-size

If I want to support ethereum with a full node. How much space do I need to host a full node as of today 2020 September?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently 165 GB, taken from https://blockchair.com/ethereum/charts/blockchain-size:

[image]

For an archive node, you need over 5TB (taken from https://etherscan.io/chartsync/chainarchive):

[image]

Comment: That is not the full chain download size. Last i check it was much more than that a few years ago.

Comment: @Patoshiパトシ Then you mean an archive node. I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: don't you need an archival node if one wants to see historic transaction data? Or does a full node offer this as well?

Comment: @Patoshiパトシ Yeah, but an archive node is not required for securing the Ethereum network. A regular full node still processes and checks all transactions. It just doesn't keep track of the state for each past block, only the last 256 blocks.